# Zend and long execution action

Tags: php, zend-framework

I would like to run action `http://site.com/rss/rss_import` which downloads many large files.
I use:

```
ignore_user_abort();
set_time_limit(0);
```

After about 60 seconds I get the following message:

> 504 Gateway timeout

When I run `rss_import.php` directly, the 504 error does not occur.
What can I do about that?

Comment: use the cli? http://www.god-object.com/2010/03/26/bootstrap-zend-framework-for-use-in-cronjobs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

504 Gateway Timeout (you are probably using nginx) is web-server-related, not php-related. The server simply stops waiting for data from the php-fcgi.

Either change the config of nginx (see http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpFastcgiModule#fastcgi_read_timeout) or use the command line as ArneRie has already suggested.

//edit: In the (unlikely) case that you are using Apache with fcgi I want to put the parameter for apache, too: https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidiotimeout